# Question about $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was reading about minimal and maximal subgroups and in one example it is mentioned that the additive group $\mathbb{Z} $ does not have minimal subgroups. I tried to prove this by assuming that $ \mathbb{Z} $ does have minimal subgroups to arrive at a contradiction, starting from the fact that the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z} $ are cyclic but it doesn't get anywhere.

Comment: It always mystifies me why the first thing people seem to try is an argument by contradiction... Note that the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are all of the form $\langle n\rangle$ for some $n\geq 0$, and that $\langle n\rangle\subseteq \langle m\rangle$ if and only if $m|n$.

Comment: Hint: If $H$ is a non-trivial subgroup, show that $2H=\{2x\mid x\in H\}$ is a proper subset of $H$ and a non-trivial subgroup.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, can you avoid an argument by contradiction to prove that $\Bbb Z$ hasn't got finite nontrivial subgroups?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @user: You can prove it by contrapositive: if $H$ is a nontrivial subgroup, then it is infinite. In any case, I don’t object to proofs by contradiction *per se*. It just mystifies me that it seems to be *the very first thing* a lot of people try *always* for *everything*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as pointed out already by @ArturoMagidin, any subgroup is of the form $\langle n\rangle$.  But there are always multiples of a given $n$ (in fact infinitely many: $n,2n,3n,\dots$).  Now the (cyclic) subgroup $\langle kn\rangle\lt\langle n\rangle$ for any $\Bbb Z\ni k\gt1$.  Thus $\langle n\rangle$ is not minimal.